# How to test dependent: :destroy with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I'd like to test my `User` models association `has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy` and have gone this far for now:

```
it "destroys dependent projects" do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  project = FactoryGirl.build(:project)

  user.projects << project
  user.destroy

  expect(Project.count).to change(-1)
end
```

but this gives out an error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Project.count).to change(-1)
     ArgumentError:
       `change` requires either an object and message (`change(obj, :msg)`) or a block (`change { }`). You passed an object but no message.
```

so I presume that `change` isn't the right matcher, is it? Can you please tell me how I could write this test without getting that error?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is the right matcher, but you're not using it the correct way:

- expect needs to receive a block containing the action to perform (in your case deleting the user)
- change needs to receive a block that produces the numerical value that is expected to change (it can also receive an object and a symbol indicating that rspec should call the named method)

The correct way is

```
expect { user.destroy }.to change { Project.count }
```

This just asserts that the numerical value changes, but does not specify by how much. To do that, chain a call to `by`:

```
expect { user.destroy }.to change { Project.count }.by(-1)
```

Comment: You can write expect `{ user.destroy }.to change(Project, :count).by(-1)` to avoid a second block

Comment: This is the way I did it all the time. However, I prefer vanboom's answer as it is more explicit. Although unlikely, if you had a bug that would pass the .by(-1) variant but fail the more explicit test, it would be a pain tracking it down and thus raise the cost tremendously

Answer (score 45):

You can also use shoulda matchers:

```
it { expect(user).to have_many(:projects).dependent(:destroy) }
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: You should include shoulda matchers in spec_helper: `require 'shoulda/matchers'`, more info on dependent: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L147-L182

Comment: Is there any other solution rather using shoulda-matchers gem?

Comment: `shoulda/matchers` required, but still throws up.

Comment: When the dependent is on but not specified in shoulda matcher on the association it is not reported as error.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
it { is_expected.to have_many(:projects).dependent(:destroy) }
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
expect { user.destroy }.to change { Project.count }.by(-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should test for the removal of the actual project.

```
expect(Project.all).not_to include project
```